# Samsung S3 Mini power save mode activity

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini, llama

I'd like to use power saving feature available in Samsung's TouchWiz in Llama but the only way to do this is to tell Llama particular activity/intent to run I guess.

As in this [thread on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1898796). I'm wondering if you know how to execute this action so I can control power saving from Llama.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an `Intent` using Llama? Or are you asking for the specific `Intent` details you would need in order to (en/dis)able power saving?

Comment: The latter. :) :)